# Unable to find element using protractor/jasmine, possibly because sendKey error

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor

I'm getting:

> Failed: No element found using locator

no matter how I program the locator (I've tried by css, by xpath, by ID.. nothing).

The webpage I'm using: https://phptravels.org/clientarea.php?incorrect=true

I should be able to get an error message after entering an incorrect username and password. The error message is stored in the CSS selector .alert.alert-danger.text-center. The error displayed is 'Login Details Incorrect. Please try again.'

No matter how I format this, I get the same element not found issue, but also when invoking sendKeys, it seems to work. That is, if I take out the offending line of code for the error message, the rest of the program passes with no errors, and thus sendKeys should be working, but when running the program I don't observe anything actually being entered in the input boxes (Unless it's entering the sendKey information and clicking the button so fast I can't see it? But then why isn't the rest of the program lightning fast?). So I'm not sure if this is actually an element not found or a sendKey error. Also, I've looked through several answers on here and there are several Wait type libraries, but when I try to use that information in my program I just get more errors.

Here is my code:

```
// newSpec.js

browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
it('should have a title', function() {
browser.get('http://phptravels.com/demo');

expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('PHPTRAVELS | Demo');
});
});

describe('Login function', function() {
it('should be able to login', function() {
browser.findElement(by.linkText('Login')).click();
expect(element(by.xpath('//div[@class="login"]')).isPresent());

}); 
});



describe('Enter name', function() {
var inputEmail = element(by.css('#inputEmail'));
var inputPassword = element(by.css('#inputPassword'));  
var goButton = element(by.css('#login'));

it('should be able to enter user name', function() {
browser.get('https://phptravels.org/clientarea.php');

     inputEmail.sendKeys('Test Test');
     inputPassword.sendKeys('Password123');


     browser.sleep(500); 
 goButton.click();
     browser.sleep(500); 

 var errorMessage = element(by.id('#.alert.alert-danger.text-center'));
 expect(errorMessage.getText()).toEqual('   Login Details Incorrect. Please        try again. ');

 });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use a CSS selector inside the `by.id` locator.

Use `by.css` or a `$` shortcut:

```
var errorMessage = $('.alert.alert-danger');
```

You can then enforce it with an [Explicit Wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) to address a possible timing issue:

```
var errorMessage = $('.alert.alert-danger');

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(errorMessage), 5000);

expect(errorMessage.getText()).toEqual('Login Details Incorrect. Please        try again.');
```

I also think you should call `waitForAngularEnabled()` inside the test itself. This is what is working for me:

```
describe('Enter name', function() {
    var inputEmail = element(by.css('#inputEmail'));
    var inputPassword = element(by.css('#inputPassword'));
    var goButton = element(by.css('#login'));

    it('should be able to enter user name', function() {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get('https://phptravels.org/clientarea.php');

        inputEmail.sendKeys('Test@test.com');
        inputPassword.sendKeys('Password123');

        browser.sleep(500);
        goButton.click();
        browser.sleep(500);

        var errorMessage = $('.alert.alert-danger');
        expect(errorMessage.getText()).toEqual('Login Details Incorrect. Please try again.');

    });
});
```

---

A note about the "by id" locator problem:

Note that (shameless self-promotion), you could've caught this problem much earlier, if you would have used `ESLint` static code analysis tool in conjunction with [`eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) - there is a [`valid-by-id` rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/valid-by-id.md) that checks the validness of `id` passed to `by.id`.

Comment: Sorry I've edited my file so many times over itself that I edited it wrong putting it in here. I changed it back to .css, still same issue. I will check out ESLint though

Comment: @JuliePixie okay, no problem, I've added more things to try. Thanks.

Comment: Now I get timeout errors (I've adjusted the timeouts values up and down, no result). Combining the lack of no element found error PLUS a timeout error leads me to believe it's sendKeys that's the culprit, especially when I adjust the timeout to be longer and I still see no keys entered. But why wouldn't sendKeys work when it seems like such a straightforward thing?

Comment: @JuliePixie alright, just to confirm, you cannot see keys entered into both email and password inputs?

Comment: Nope and thanks for sticking with me on this. The test case if I end it at clicking the button will execute properly with no errors, but at no point do I actually see anything entered in the two fields.

Comment: @JuliePixie not a problem. Updated with what is working for me. Check it out. Hope that helps.

Comment: Worked! I'll have to adjust the spacing and change the email back to my personal email but I'm seeing sendkeys working now. I think as a new programmer I get confused by scope sometimes. Thanks so much